# Delete nodes on XML using xmlstarlet searching

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces, xmlstarlet

I need to delete all `<row>` nodes with `<integer>3489943</integer>` using xmlstarlet but I cannot figure out the xpath.

A fragment of the file is as follows

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<backup xmlns="http://www.atlassian.com/ao" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <database>
    <meta key="database.name" value="Oracle"/>
    <meta key="database.version" value="Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit"/>
    <meta key="database.minorVersion" value="1"/>
    <meta key="database.majorVersion" value="12"/>
    <meta key="driver.name" value="Oracle JDBC driver"/>
    <meta key="driver.version" value="12.2.0.1.0"/>
  </database>
  <table name="AO_0A5972_NOTIFICATION_SETTING">
    <column name="ID" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" sqlType="2" precision="20"/>
    <column name="KEY" primaryKey="false" autoIncrement="false" sqlType="12" precision="255"/>
    <column name="TYPE" primaryKey="false" autoIncrement="false" sqlType="12" precision="255"/>
    <column name="USER_KEY" primaryKey="false" autoIncrement="false" sqlType="12" precision="255"/>
    <column name="VALUE" primaryKey="false" autoIncrement="false" sqlType="12" precision="255"/>
  </table>
  <data tableName="AO_733371_EVENT_PARAMETER">
      <column name="EVENT_ID"/>
      <column name="ID"/>
      <column name="NAME"/>
      <column name="VALUE"/>
      <row>
          <integer>3243959</integer>
          <integer>59623887</integer>
          <string>object#issue#created_date#0</string>
          <string>1590646764000</string>
      </row>
      <row>
          <integer>3489943</integer>
          <integer>64127343</integer>
          <string>object#issue#created_date#0</string>
          <string>1593114489000</string>
      </row>
      <row>
        <integer>3489943</integer>
        <integer>64127355</integer>
        <string>jira#status#oldstring#0</string>
        <string>To Do</string>
      </row>
  </data>
</backup>
```

I have tried this but no luck

```
xmlstarlet ed -d "/backup/data[@tableName='AO_733371_EVENT_PARAMETER']/row[integer=3489943]" sample.xml
```

Thanks,

Enrique

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file uses XML namespaces.

```
xmlstarlet edit -N xyz='http://www.atlassian.com/ao' --delete '//xyz:row[xyz:integer="3489943"]' file.xml
```

Comment: Actually I have more `<data tableName="ANOTHER NAME">` entries that I want to keep intact, so the working query is `xmlstarlet edit -N xyz='http://www.atlassian.com/ao' --delete '/xyz:backup/xyz:data[@tableName="AO_733371_EVENT_PARAMETER"]/xyz:row[xyz:integer="3489943"]'` . Your answer put me in the right track. Thank you so much.